# how to push the object keys and values to array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object

I need to push the key value pair to new array and should build the mongodb $match query.

```
const queryFormat = (payload) => {
    delete payload.userEventId
    var query = {}
     var res = []
    for(key in payload) {
        if(typeof(payload[key])) {
       res.push({ [key]: payload[key] })
        }
        else {
            res.push({"$in" :{ [key]: payload[key] }})
        }
    }
    console.log(res[3])
    query['$match'] = {"$and" :res}
    console.log(query)    
}


const payload = {
    id :1,
    name : 'Alfred',
    location : 'moon',
    values : [{name: 'u',age:9}]
}
queryFormat(payload)
```

**expected output**

```
{"$match":{"$and":[{id:1},{name:"Alfred"},{location:"moon"},{"values":{"$in":[{name:"u"},{age: 9}]} }]}}
```

**output I got**

```
{"$match":{"$and":[{id:1},{name:"Alfred"},{location:"moon"},{"values":{"$in":[{name:"u",age: 9}]} }]}}
```

How to deal with it
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are specifying the key as `"key"`

Use `[]` to specify that you need the value of `key` as the key

```js
const queryFormat = (payload) => {
    delete payload.userEventId
    var query = {}
     var res = []
    for(key in payload) {
       res.push({ [key]: payload[key] })
    }
    query['$match'] = {"$and" :res}
    console.log(query)    
}


const payload = {
    id :1,
    name : 'Alfred',
    location : 'moon'
}
queryFormat(payload)
```